# tcpclient listening implementation

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I am trying to implement a tcp client listening function. This means that after connection established with server, this tcp client just sit there and waiting for new data to arrive.
Here is my code but when it runs, it complain about not been able to read anything from the 
network stream. But the server hasn't started sending data yet. I guess the complains is because
of the timeout in tcp client.

Is this the right way to do it?

```
   public void listen(dataHandler processDataFuc)
    {
        NetworkStream stream;

        Byte[] data_buffer = new Byte[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];

        if(!this.Connected)
        {
            this.Connect();
        }

        while (!this.terminate_listening)
        {
            stream = main_client.GetStream();

            while (stream.Read(data_buffer, 0, data_buffer.Length) > 0)
            {
                processDataFuc(data_buffer);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, it'll do what you want, but it's not ideal. I'd first suggest moving `stream = main_client.GetStream();` out of the `while` loop, as you're just getting the same stream over and over. Also, using `NetworkStream.Read` isn't the best way to perform a continuous read if you're expecting intermittent data over a long period of time, as it's holding up a thread just for that one task; better to use `BeginRead` and pass in a callback, which will return immediately but later alert you when data is available (via the callback).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the methods [EstablishConnection()](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/src/6f43226c569a/NetworkCommsDotNet/Connection.cs#cl-408) and [IncomingDataSyncWorker()](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/src/6f43226c569a/NetworkCommsDotNet/Connection.cs#cl-697) (synchronous) or [IncomingPacketHandler()](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/src/6f43226c569a/NetworkCommsDotNet/Connection.cs#cl-781) (asynchronous) for examples of what you want to do. All these methods are part of [networkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/) an opensource network communication library.

Comment: It's open source, but under GPL. So you can't use this library for closed source software without an agreement with the developers.

Answer (score 0):

What version of .Net are you using?
If you are using .Net 4.0 or 4.5, then you can use `ReadAsync()` instead of `Read()`.
Consider this:

```
public async void listen(dataHandler processDataFuc)
{
    NetworkStream stream;

    Byte[] data_buffer = new Byte[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];

    if(!this.Connected)
        this.Connect();

    stream = main_client.GetStream();

    while (!this.terminate_listening)
    {            
        await stream.ReadAsync(data_buffer, 0, data_buffer.Length)
        processDataFuc(data_buffer);
    }
}
```

In such way, `ReadAsync()` will waits in a separate Thread until server sends some Data. Then the rest of your code will execute.